# Laravel array merge 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have 3 arrays that I need to merge together but can't figure out how?

`array 1`

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "admin98@wassiah.test"
  1 => "admin69@wassiah.test"
  2 => "admin25@wassiah.test"
  3 => null
]
```

`array 2`

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "one"
  1 => "three"
  2 => "two"
  3 => null
]
```

`array 3`

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "10"
  1 => "11"
  2 => null
  3 => null
]
```

And I need to make new array like this:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "admin98@wassiah.test"
    "name" => "one"
    "id" => "10"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "admin69@wassiah.test
    "name" => "three"
    "id" => "11"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "admin25@wassiah.test"
    "name" => "two"
    "id" => null
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => null
    "name" => null
    "id" => null
  ]
]
```

`Code`

```
$mails = $request->input('mails'); // array 1
$names = $request->input('names'); // array 2
$heirIds = $request->input('ids'); // array 3
```

Any idea?

Comment: Whether your array will be of same size ? ie arr1 ,arr2 and arr3 ?

Comment: @Ajith yes they are always same size

Comment: You can iterate to get your required result, i can provide the code now

Comment: @Ajith will be appreciate it .

Comment: Loop over the items, create a new array with the desired keys and the values from each of your arrays

Comment: @brombeer I've tried to loop couldn't make it that's why I said `can't figure out how?` I've tried `array_add`, `array_merge` `array_combine` all failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(
"admin98@wassiah.test",
"admin97@wassiah.test",
"admin96@wassiah.test",
"",
);

$arr2 = array(
"one",
"three",
"two",
"",
);

$arr3 = array(
"10",
"11",
"",
"",
);

$result = array();
$count = count($arr1);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $result[$i]['email'] = $arr1[$i];
    $result[$i]['name'] = $arr2[$i];
    $result[$i]['id'] = $arr3[$i];
}



echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

Comment: As easy as this